# C string atoi int array

Tags: c, arrays

## I want to do the following stuff:

1. Convert input string to int.
2. Sum up an int array by using pointers and a for loop.
3. If the user types nothing but only ENTER, the program will print the answer.

#### My code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i, a[10], sum = 0;
    int * b;
    b = a;
    char c[10];
    printf ("Please enter some numbers:\n");

    for(i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        (void) fgets(c, (sizeof * b), stdin);
        if(c[0] == '\n')
        {
            break;
        }
        *(b + i) = atoi(c);
        sum = sum + *(b + i);
    }
    printf ("sum : %d \n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

### There is something weird that I can't figure out why.

#### It only works fine with two-digits:

```
$Please enter some numbers:
$32
$31
$1
$
$sum:64
```

#### If I type three-digits, it directly prints result:

```
$Please enter some numbers:
$123
$sum:123


$Please enter some numbers:
$12
$123
$sum:135
```

#### If there are more than three digits, the program will sum up rest of the digits.

```
$Please enter some numbers:
$2123
$
$sum:215    //The sum became 212+3.



$Please enter some numbers:
$12345
$11
$
$sum:179    //The sum became 123+45+11.



$Please enter some numbers:
$123456
$sum:579    //If the number of digits is a multiple of 3, this program directly prints sum(=123+456).
```

#### If someone can help me, I would be grateful. Thank you for reading this long question.

Comment: `fgets(c,sizeof* b,stdin);` --> `fgets(c,sizeof(c),stdin);`

Comment: Why do you read the size of b's value? sizeof* b will be converted into 4 or 2, depending on your system - either way - that's not your intention. You should read sizeof(c) - 10.

Comment: Oops! I am too careless. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

This is wrong:

```
fgets(c,sizeof* b,stdin);
```

`sizeof *b` is the size of an `int` (tipically 4) and you want room for `10` characters:

```
fgets(c,sizeof c,stdin);
```

And notice that you don't need to strip the trailing new-line after `fgets` in this concrete case, from the `atoi` man:

> The string can contain additional characters after those that form the
>   integral number, which are ignored and have no effect on the behavior
>   of this function.

Answer (score 3):

```
fgets(c,sizeof(c),stdin);

size_t n = strlen(c);

if(n>0 && c[n-1] == '\n')
{
   c[n-1] = '\0';
}
```

There is a newline character that comes with `fgets()` you need to get rid of it.

Then convert the string to integer you don't know how many integers are there.

```
   char *p;

    p = strtok(c," ");
    while(p != NULL)
    {
       b[i++] = atoi(p);
       p = strtok(c, NULL);
    }
```

Do the addition of the integers and make sure you have a check for `i<10` before accessing the array.

If your termination condition is `\n` before stripping the newline you can do the check what you are already doing.

Comment: Or to use `strcspn` ==>>> `p[strcspn(p, "\n")] = 0;`